# Idiomatic way to flatMap Observable to Completable

Tags: java, rx-java

I need to `flatMap` an `Observable` to a `Completable`. I have this code:

```
public Completable doSomething() {
    return repository.getUser()
        .flatMap(new Func1<Action, Observable<Object>>(){
            @Override
            public Observable<Object> call(User user) {
                return Completable.merge(
                    doTask1(), //returns Completable
                    doTask2(), //returns Completable
                    doTask3() //returns Completable
                ).toObservable();
            }
    }).toCompletable();
}
```

and it works. But I think it is a bit messy. I'm converting the completable (from `Completable.merge()`) to `Observable` and then I'm doing the opposite (`toCompletable()`). Is there a better way to do this? Something like this:

```
public Completable doSomething() {
    return repository.getUser()
        .flatMap(new Func1<Action, Completable>(){
            @Override
            public Completable call(User user) {
                return Completable.merge(
                    doTask1(), //returns Completable
                    doTask2(), //returns Completable
                    doTask3() //returns Completable
                );
            }
    });
}
```

Observable is "converted" directly to Completable using `flatMap`.

Comment: flatMapCompletable()?

Comment: I believe `flatMapCompletable()` is rxjava2 only. Correction rxjava from 1.2.7.

Comment: That's right. Unfortunatelly, in the version I'm using that feature doesn't exist.